# If we're wearing a metal watch, do we get an electric shock on our wrist when we're charged and touch a conductor?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, everyday-life

As the charge would flow to/from the watch, assuming I'm insulated from the ground with rubber soles, or standing on glass.

Comment: Is the conductor being touched a bare line voltage (> = 120vac) conductor? Is it your skin touching it or is it the metal watch touching it?

Comment: It can be, yes.
The skin would be touching it.